# How to contact with gmail support?

Tags: gmail, sms

Recently I've found that I stopped receiving any sms messages from Google (calendar notification, 2-step verification messages).

After small investigation I found out that all customers that have moved their numbers from one to another carrier are affected (I moved mine from 2degrees to Vodafone).

After consulting with Vodafone engineers and after they explained the issue roots briefly I decided to contact to GMail support, but the only way I've found is [their forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/tt6_qs4CgEY/hwjSyD84E4sJ).

Obviously that request changed nothing - Google employees don't seem to visit the forums frequently.

So - does anybody have any other ideas about how to file a bug for them, because the whole country is affected.

PS: I live in New Zealand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure about the cause of the problem, you could try https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/gmail/report-an-issue
If that doesn't work, consider making a blog post, contact Googlers on twitter and Google+..
I know it sucks and there's no direct and reliable contact channel. Or find their office location, go out there with a huge sign. :) Your best bet is to raise as much stink as possible, hopefully that somebody at Googleplex will notice your issue.

Comment: "you could try" - I have already done that and even gave a link in the question :-) well, thanks for another ideas :-)

Comment: hmm, for some reason I didn't realize that post was by you.
Oh, you could also try submitting your story to consumerist.com. They are mostly a US site, but maybe they'll pick up your plight as well.

Comment: The forum does not work. Error 454

Comment: @Alex I just tried that url and it still works here...